# How can I sum a column given by a specific index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i sum a column given by index? i tried to use 'for row in list', but it results a TypeError.

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2RZQ.png)

[index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhbbE.png)

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fUNG.png)

Comment: Where is your attempt of "for row in list?"

Comment: column_sum = 0
    for row in list:
        column_sum += row[i]

Comment: See [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do as you say. However, the sum of the names is not possible if you initialize the `column_sum` to 0 (which is an integer).

The sum of the names does not seem relevant. But if you want the function `get_total` to work on any column, you should first check if the variables are integers. If not, then return 0 for instance.

```
def get_total(index, stations):
    if not stations:
        # The list is empty
        return 0
    if type(stations[0][index]) is int:
        # The sum is possible
        return sum([station[index] for station in stations])
    return 0
```